# How to add an object to the key/legend in gnuplot?

Tags: key, gnuplot, legend

I use gnuplot to plot several graphs.

I use the `set key` command in order to have a legend of my graphs.

Now I added a huge rectangle with `set object rect` to mark an important zone in the diagram.

What I need is the discription (or better the title) of that rectangle in the key box.

How can I add the title or label of a specific object to the key box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can add arbitrary objects to the legend, but you can add rectangles by using an empty `boxes` plot:

```
set object rectangle from 5,10 to 7,60 fs empty border 2
plot x**2 w l, NaN title "Region of interest" with boxes lt 2
```

[image]